# Value is added to scope but inaccessible from modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a value to the controller's $scope once a button is pressed.

This will be accessed by the modal.

After the button is pressed, the value (`item`) is added to the $scope as expected.

[image]

However, in the modal **phrase-item** below, when I attempt to access the value it is not visible:

```
<ion-modal-view>

    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">{{ item }}</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button button-stable" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>

</ion-modal-view>
```

This is my code so far.

**controller.js**

```
/**
*
*/
function PhraseListCtrl($scope, $stateParams, CategoryService, ModalService) {

    $scope.categoryId = $stateParams.categoryId;
    $scope.category = $stateParams.category;

    CategoryService.getCategoryDetail($scope.categoryId).then(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.categoryDetail = dataResponse.data;

        var replacers = CategoryService.getCategoryFilter();

        $scope.categoryDetail.forEach(function(e){
            Object.keys(replacers).forEach(function(key){
                e['phrase_filter'] = e['phrase_filter'].replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), replacers[key]);
            })
        })

    })


    // Get value of button

    $scope.getItem = function(item) {
            $scope.item = item;
    }


    // Modals

    $scope.phraseItemModal = function() {
            var vm = $scope;
            console.log(vm);
            ModalService.show('templates/modals/phrase-item.html', 'PhraseListCtrl as vm');
        }

}
```

**services.js**

```
/**
*
*/
function CategoryService($http) {

    this.getCategoryList = function () {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dingocv.herokuapp.com/api/category/',
        });

    }


    this.getCategoryDetail = function (categoryId) {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dingocv.herokuapp.com/api/category/' + categoryId,
        });

    }

    this.getCategoryFilter = function () {

        var replacers = {
            '{{group}}' : '<a ng-click="getItem(\'Group\'); phraseItemModal()" class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">group</a>',
            '{{attribute}}' : '<a ng-click="phraseItemModal()" class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">attribute</a>',
            '{{factor}}' : '<a ng-click="phraseItemModal()" class="button button-small button-outline button-assertive button-side-padding">factor</a>',
            '{{person}}' : '<a ng-click="phraseItemModal()" class="button button-small button-outline button-positive button-side-padding">person</a>'
        }

        return replacers;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it required to have a separate controller for the modal? It sounds like it may not be in the same $scope.

Comment: @NoobSter which other scope would it be in?